# Counter unable to run in PowerShell/IDLE not responding to large list?

Tags: python, powershell, counter, python-idle

I am a complete beginner, so forgive the probably-obvious question. I have a list of roughly ~800,000 items that I am trying to run through Counter. When I try to open the script in IDLE, it stops responding, and when I try to run the script through PowerShell, it throws back an error in Line 9 (the line the large list is populated on). Is there a cap on the number of items that Counter can run?

For brevity's sake, I am not including my whole list here of course, but this is my basic script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
from itertools import count
from urllib.request import urlopen
from collections import Counter

from collections import Counter
list1 = [list, items, here, et cetera]
print(Counter(list1))
```

This is the complete script -- [Full script with list data.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ChieTluETrt1U4eS4pR5iTYcrAaXyDu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: So you left out the line that actually causes the error? Seems obvious where the problem is - what exactly is the error that line is causing? Is there a reason you have all your data inside your code, or is it populated in some other fashion that you could share?

Comment: @Grismar It just cuts off in the middle of a word, and if I edit the list order it cuts off at a different word roughly the same distance down the list. I have all of my data inside the code because I don't know how else to include it. I've edited my post to attach the full code.

Comment: Your list has syntactical errors, each element of the list should be quoted...

Comment: How did you even create that file?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The full code took 20-30 seconds to load.  IDLE quits responding because the text widget of the tk GUI framework it uses freezes with super-duper long lines.  10000 chars is enough to bring it almost to a stop.  100000s or 1000000s should completely freeze is.

The error in Powershell has nothing to do with IDLE.  Posting a sample list with a few unquoted items would have been enough to expose that error.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the recommended maximum line length for Python is 79 characters https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length your expectations should have been moderate at best.

It's generally a bad practice to keep your data in your code. If you must, you should at least properly quote and escape each string in the list, e.g.:

```
list1 = ['sherlock holmes', 'something\\else', 'a \'quote\' here', ...]
```

But it's a lot easier and more robust to just put your data in a text file:

```
sherlock holmes
star wars
star wars sequel trilogy
...
ya lit
books
```

The text file need no escaping, although you may need something to deal with line endings, which appear to have been escaped as `\xa0` in your data.

And then read the file from code:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    list1 = f.read().splitlines()
```

From the partial escaping, it seems likely something generated your 'code' to begin with - you may want to generate it again without the escaping, and just output a clean text file, and only deal with the line endings in a sensible way.

Comment: I don't get the point about 79 chars. That's for *humans*, no? Does Python have an issue with very long code lines?

Comment: Did you mean `f.read()`?

Comment: @KellyBundy it is for humans, but there's no reasonable expectation for source code (which is for humans by definition) to contain lines of unlimited length. There's no specified maximum length in the specs that I'm aware of, but anything beyond 79 characters gets frowns, 10,000s of characters is just ludicrous. If code wasn't for humans, we'd write bytecode - much more efficient, none of these issues.

Comment: Hmm. I see no reason why that would be limited, so I do expect it to not be limited by Python. I mean, I agree that to us, that's data, and we shouldn't put such a big amount into what, for us, is code. But for Python, our code *is* data. Why would it care? (I know that *deeply nested* data in code can cause issues for the parser, but the OP's data looks flat.)

Comment: There's is no hard reason why a text editor should limit the size of files it can edit, but there are practical reasons and reasons that arise from other functional requirements that mean such limits are common for most text editors. The same will be true for Python compilers. I agree that there is no reason (none that have been accepted so far as PEP at least) for such a limit to exist for the *language* - but keep adding data to a single line of code and most compilers will break at some point. Apart from .py being a spectacularly bad choice to store data for other reasons, why risk it?